# Nested Directory Searching in Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a recursive loop over a few directories. This works:

```
FOR /R "Dir1" %%f IN (*.c *.cpp *.h) DO (
  echo %%f
)
FOR /R "Dir2" %%f IN (*.c *.cpp *.h) DO (
  echo %%f
)
```

But since this is silly (the `echo` part is actually a block of commands, and the number of directories is large), I tried this:

```
FOR %%d IN (Dir1 Dir2) DO (
  FOR /R "%%d" %%f IN (*.c *.cpp *.h) DO (
    echo %%f
  )
)
```

Which didn't work (it didn't run anything). Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `FOR /R` doesn't like late-expansion variables as the search path. I ran [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and found that cmd.exe was actually attempting to access a file/directory named `%d`!

One documented feature of `/R` is that if you leave out the directory, it will search the CWD.
I used this to come up with an altered form of your script that appears to function.

```
FOR %%d IN (Dir1 Dir2) DO (
    PUSHD "%%~d"
    FOR /R %%f IN (*.c *.cpp *.h) DO (
        ECHO %%f
    )
    POPD
)
```

FWIW, for the sake of script maintainability, if there were more than a few dirs, rather than list them in the command, I would put the directories to search in a separate text file and use `FOR /F` to iterate over them. Perhaps you only wrote it like this to provide a minimal working example.